# My DTO showing null for one object and the correct value for the other

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm learning how to properly use DTOs and so far everything was going well until I got this problem:

I have a Model called Student:

```
@Data
@Document
@Builder
public class Student {

  @Id
  private String id;
  @Indexed(unique = true)
  private Name name;
  @Indexed(unique = true)
  private String email;
  private Gender gender;
  private Address address;
  private List<String> favoriteSubjects;
  private BigDecimal totalSpentInBooks;
  private LocalDateTime created;
```

}

Than I create a DTO to fetch some data:

```
@Data
public class StudentDto {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String email;
  private String country;
```

}

Here is the response using the DTO from Postman:

```
{
    "firstName": "Gabriel",
    "lastName": "Vendramini",
    "email": "gabriel.vendramini@email.com",
    "country": null
}
```

Here is the same response but with no DTO:

```
{
    "id": "61f7d87bb4534b452993b02e",
    "name": {
        "firstName": "Gabriel",
        "lastName": "Vendramini"
    },
    "email": "gabriel.vendramini@email.com",
    "gender": "MALE",
    "address": {
        "country": "Brazil",
        "city": "Sao Paulo",
        "postCode": "08006"
    },
    "favoriteSubjects": [
        "Computer Science",
        "Mathematic",
        "Physic"
    ],
    "totalSpentInBooks": 10,
    "created": "2022-01-31T13:39:23.023"
}
```

Here are the Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/get-all")
public ResponseEntity<List<Student>> fetchAllStudents() {
   log.info("Get All Students - Controller Call");
   return ResponseEntity.ok(studentService.getAllStudents());
}

@GetMapping("/get-all-dto")
public ResponseEntity<List<StudentDto>> fetchAllStudentsDto() {
   log.info("Get All Students With DTO - Controller Call");
   return ResponseEntity.ok(studentService.getAllStudents().stream().map(studen 
   t -> modelMapper.map(student,
        StudentDto.class)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

}

Here are the Models for Address and Name:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Address {
  private String country;
  private String city;
  private String postCode;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Name {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
}
```

The structure is the same for both. I tried to pass all the attributes from Address, change the order.

Comment: You need to tell your mapper what field to map to what.

Comment: Is the country set in the code? Because if it isn't, then it won't be set in the resulting JSON.

The mapper an only map properties with the same name (and probably the same type). The country comes from address, which means you need to explicitly tell the mapper how to map the country.

Comment: You are saying in here: "map(studen 
   t -> modelMapper.map(student,
        StudentDto.class)).collect(Collectors.toList()));"?

Comment: @RobSpoor I added the models from Name and Address but the country is only a String value.

Comment: But my question here is why it fetches the data for Name and for Address it doesn't?